# Can't see Flutter Inspector in View > Tool Windows in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Installed Flutter & Dart SDK, checked 'Open Flutter Inspector view on app launch' under Languages & Frameworks > Flutter.

Android Studio Sidebar

[image]

I can see 'Open Flutter DevTools' button under Run tab, which opens DevTools in browser. However, the inspector doesn't work properly (widget tree disappears when i select a widget, object doesn't open in Android Studio when double clicked).

Comment: did you add flutter plugin?

Comment: I have installed the flutter plugin. Using the same setup, the Inspector does work on my Macbook, however, it does not work on Windows.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you manage to get it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can check from tools, tap to open it.

[image]

Now pin the tab to have always on bottom

[image]

Comment: Layout Inspector and Flutter don't appear in the Tools dropdown.